# Polar plot thetagrid label

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to draw a polar plot using following script. I would like to have angle of the thetagrid labels align with the grid line. (as shown in the figure)

I have modified the code according to tom's answer. The labels of the left half of the plot appears to be upside down.

```
from pylab import *
fig = figure()
rc('grid', color='r', linewidth=0.5, linestyle='-')
data1 = loadtxt("1.dat")
ax = plt.subplot(111,polar=True)
x= data1[:,0]
y= data1[:,1]
plt.scatter(x,y, s=0.1,color='r' )
gl, gt = ax.set_rgrids(range(10,81,10))
for l in gl: l.set_ls('') 
(lines,labels)=thetagrids( range(0,360,18), ("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF", "GG", "HH", "II", "KK", "LL","MM","NN","OO","PP","QQ","RR","SS","TT","UU","VV"))
for label,angle in zip(labels,range(0,360,18)):
    label.set_rotation(90-angle)
    ax.set_theta_offset(np.pi/2.0)
    ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
    ax.set_yticklabels([])
    show()
```

[image]

Comment: see my edit, which addresses your edited question

Comment: Thanks tom! for else condition, 270-angle works better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the angle of the labels after setting the `thetagrids`. You need to set it to `90-angle`. If you keep the returned `labels` from `thetagrids`, you can loop over the labels and use `label.set_rotation`

```
(lines,labels) = thetagrids( range(0,360,18), ("XXXXX","YYYYY","ZZZZ","PPPP"))

for label,angle in zip(labels,range(0,360,18)):
    label.set_rotation(90-angle)
```

[image]

**EDIT**

As for your edited question. You can just have a condition that says if the  angle is >180 then use `270-angle`. Something like:

```
for label,angle in zip(labels,range(0,360,18)):
    if angle <= 180:
         label.set_rotation(90-angle)
    else:
         label.set_rotation(270-angle)
```

[image]

**EDIT 2**

And, as for your question in the comment below, you can change the tick label offset using the `frac` argument to `thetagrids`. From the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.thetagrids):

> `frac` is the fraction of the polar axes radius at which to place the label (1 is the edge). e.g., 1.05 is outside the axes and 0.95 is inside the axes.

So, to increase the padding between the axes edge and the label, just make `frac>1`, e.g.

```
(lines,labels)=thetagrids(range(0,360,18), 
                          ("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF", "GG", "HH", "II", "KK", "LL","MM","NN","OO","PP","QQ","RR","SS","TT","UU","VV"),
                          frac=1.2)
```

[image]

Comment: This suggestion works perfectly. But, I'd like to add padding for the labels. I tried tight_layout() and didn't work..